# Access vba : How to minimize application when user clicks minimize button in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

What exactly I want is,

Whenever user clicks minimize button in a form, I want the form, Not to minimize itself but to minimize the whole application.

Details:
1. I have an access form which runs maximised
2. I enabled minimize and maximize button of that form
3. I made it a modal and popup form
3. Users will click minimize button whenever they want to minimize.
4. But only form is minimized and main access window is visible

Now here's what I want..
I want that minimize button, do nothing to the form, but minimize the whole access application..

My wish is to make it feel like a customized app..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e04b3af9-f26d-40bf-9622-f3a232201f59/minimise-access-application?forum=accessdev

Comment: Hey Brino,
Thanks for a quick reply...

However what I need is a little different than the link you quoted..

The link says docmd.minimize and docmd.runcommand acappminimize... That would be right if I have a button in my form to minimize... But what I want is the minimize button of the form (not created by me, but by enabling minmax buttons) to work as minimize button of the application..

Whenever user clicks to minimize the form, the form should stay as it is but the application as a whole should be minimized...

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA Command

`Application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize`

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't read your comment about wanting to control the forms minimize button.  It's not impossible but it's not easy either.  You'll have to Hook the Form's Window using Windows API Calls. Start here: [Completely Hide the MS Access Application Window](http://www.devhut.net/2011/02/15/ms-access-vba-minimizemaximize-access-application/)

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas.. That really helped...

I would quote an improvement that solved my problem...

1. Whenever a form is minimized, it's width comes to 2400 (in my pc, may differ in others)
2. So I wrote code in Resize event "If Me.WindowWidth = 2400 then call fSetAccessWindow(SW_SHOWMINIMIZED) end If"

Now whenever form is minimized, it checks width, and minimizes whole application using the code in the link you provided...